# Handling CompressorException in Java8 Streams

Tags: exception, java-8, stream

I have a static method for reading .bz2 files, it throws checked IOException and org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException. The function signature is:

```
private static MyClass readFile(String fileName) throws IOException, CompressorException{
//…
}
```

Trying to use this method outright with Java8 streams gets compile time errors in Intellij;

```
unhandled exceptions: java.io.IOException, org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException
```

So following advice from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions), among others, I’ve tried the following but am stuck on how to handle the CompressorException object. Following it’s [ctor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.14/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/CompressorException.html) I’ve tried as below but Intellij still complains the CompressorException is unhandled:

```
files.stream().forEach(i -> {
    try{
        readFile(i);
    } catch (IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Throwable ex){
        throw new CompressorException("compressorException", ex);//error!!!
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, instead of **catching** it like you're doing with the IOException, you're **throwing it**. Don't. Catch it just like you're doing with the IOException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JB Nizet mentioned in the comment, you cannot throw any `Exception` from the lambda function inside `foreach` function.

You need to replace your current implementation:

```
catch (Throwable ex){
        throw new CompressorException("compressorException", ex);//error!!!
}
```

to either the following or not throw the `RuntimeException` at all.

```
catch (Throwable ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("compressorException", ex);
}
```

---

The reason for the above behaviour is that the [`Stream.foreach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method has the following signature and doesn't throw any exception as part of the signature.

```
void forEachOrdered(Consumer<? super T> action)
```